# Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a case insensitive version of the [:contains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) jQuery selector or should I do the work manually by looping over all elements and comparing their .text() to my string?

Comment: For jQuery 8.1 + check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2196683/1671639)

Comment: ^ That's 1.8.1, not 8.1.

Comment: Good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795752/jquery-usage-of-contains-and-tolowercase).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

What I ended up doing for jQuery 1.2 is :

```
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.expr[':'], { 
        Contains : "jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0" 
});
```

This will extend jquery to have a :Contains selector that is case insensitive, the :contains selector remains unchanged.

Edit: For jQuery 1.3 (thanks @user95227) and later you need

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
     return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

Edit: 
Apparently accessing the DOM directly by using

```
(a.textContent || a.innerText || "")
```

instead of

```
jQuery(a).text()
```

In the previous expression speeds it up considerably so try at your own risk if speed is an issue. (see [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171662/john) 's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407434/is-there-any-way-to-speed-up-this-solution-for-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contai))

Latest edit: For jQuery 1.8 it should be:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to let folks know that the solution as described by @Pat and others for jQuery 1.3 also works for 1.4.3.

Comment: Link to @John's question/answer since the link here was deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407434/is-there-any-way-to-speed-up-this-solution-for-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contai

Comment: This doesn't work for jQuery 1.8. See seagullJS's answer below for an updated version -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113443/560114

Answer (score 108):

To make it optionally case insensitive:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/278

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
  {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
    .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});
```

then use `:containsi` instead of `:contains`

Comment: adding a new function is best than overwrite to me, I now use this option (works like a charm)

Comment: this should be added to the standard jquery library

Answer (score 41):

As of jQuery 1.3, this method is deprecated. To get this to work it needs to be defined as a function:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

Answer (score 39):

If someone (like me) is interested what do *a* and *m[3]* mean in *Contains* definition.

---

**KEY/LEGEND: Params made available by jQuery for use in the selector definitions:**

*r* = jQuery array of elements being scrutinised. (eg: *r.length* = Number of elements)

*i* = index of element currently under scrutiny, within array *r*.

*a* = element currently under scrutiny. Selector statement must return true to include it in its matched results.

*m[2]* = nodeName or * that we a looking for (left of colon).

*m[3]* = param passed into the :selector(param). Typically an index number, as in *:nth-of-type(5)*, or a string, as in *:color(blue)*.

Answer (score 32):

In jQuery 1.8 you will need to use

```
jQuery.expr[":"].icontains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {                                                                                                                                                                
    return function (elem) {                                                            
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;        
    };                                                                                  
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Just updated to 1.8 and this stopped working .

Comment: thanx for the update. Just updated to JQuery 1.8 and it stopped working

Answer (score 15):

A variation that seems to perform slightly faster and that also **allows regular expressions** is:

```
jQuery.extend (
    jQuery.expr[':'].containsCI = function (a, i, m) {
        //-- faster than jQuery(a).text()
        var sText   = (a.textContent || a.innerText || "");     
        var zRegExp = new RegExp (m[3], 'i');
        return zRegExp.test (sText);
    }
);
```

---

Not only is this case-insensitive, but it allows powerful searches like:

- `$("p:containsCI('\\bup\\b')")`   (Matches "Up" or "up", but not "upper", "wakeup", etc.)
- `$("p:containsCI('(?:Red|Blue) state')")`   (Matches "red state" or "blue state", but not "up state", etc.)
- `$("p:containsCI('^\\s*Stocks?')")`   (Matches "stock" or "stocks", but only at the start of the paragraph (ignoring any leading whitespace).)

Answer (score 12):

May be late.... but,

I'd prefer to go this way..

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
"MyCaseInsensitiveContains": function(elem, i, match, array) {
return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}
});
```

This way, you **DO NOT** tamper with jQuery's NATIVE *'.contains'*... You may need the default one later...if tampered with, you might find yourself back to ***stackOverFlow***...

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

The update code works great in 1.3, but "contains" should be lower case on the first letter unlike the previous example.

Comment: I think he wanted a distinct function so that both `:contains` and `:Contains` would both work simultaneously.

Comment: "the :contains selector remains unchanged."

Answer (score 5):

Refer below to use ":contains" to find text ignoring its case sensitivity from an HTML code,

```
 $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
            return function( elem ) {
                return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
            };
        });
        $("#searchTextBox").keypress(function() {
          if($("#searchTextBox").val().length > 0){
            $(".rows").css("display","none");
            var userSerarchField = $("#searchTextBox").val();
            $(".rows:contains('"+ userSerarchField +"')").css("display","block");
          } else {
            $(".rows").css("display","block");
          }              
        });
```

You can also use this link to find case ignoring code based on your jquery version,
[Make jQuery :contains Case-Insensitive](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/)

Answer (score 3):

A faster version using regular expressions.

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(el, i, m) { // checks for substring (case insensitive)
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;

    var pattern = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    return pattern.test($(el).text());
};
```

Comment: Excellent job! Thank you very much. I believe that this is the best and most up-to-date response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the following not working...

```
// This doesn't catch flac or Flac
$('div.story span.Quality:not(:contains("FLAC"))').css("background-color", 'yellow');
```

This works and without the need for an extension

```
$('div.story span.Quality:not([data*="flac"])').css("background-color", 'yellow');
```

This works too, but probably falls into the "manually looping" category....

```
$('div.story span.Quality').contents().filter(function()
{
  return !/flac/i.test(this.nodeValue);
}).parent().css("background-color", 'yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

New a variable I give it name subString and put string you want to search in some elements text. Then using Jquery selector select elements you need like my example `$("elementsYouNeed")` and filter by `.filter()`. In the `.filter()` it will compare each elements in `$("elementsYouNeed")` with the function.

In the function i using `.toLowerCase()` for element text also subString that can avoid case sensitive condition and check if there is a subString in it. After that the `.filter()` method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements.

Now you can get the match elements in matchObjects and do whatever you want.

```
var subString ="string you want to match".toLowerCase();

var matchObjects = $("elementsYouNeed").filter(function () {return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(subString) > -1;});
```