# Jquery: Selecting images with a specific source?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've looked high and low through the docs and internet, and damn if I can't figure this out.

I would like to use jquery to select all images with a specific source and apply a tool tip to them.  I have the tooltip working fine when I'm finding the target with classes, but I figured it would be a bit more efficient and avoid adding unneeded classes when I should be able to select all the images with a known img source.  The code that I think should work is:

```
$("img[src*='phone']")
```

The image tag in the source is:

```
<img src='images/icons/Phone-32x32.png'>
```

Using Firebug's Dom inspector, the img element has the following source:

```
"http://www.deleted.com/v2/images/icons/Phone-32x32.png"
```

I've dicked around with various waves of selecting it, and it's beyound me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Ugh... The issue was capitalization! Changed it to:

```
$("img[src*='Phone']")
```

Now it works fine.  Please ignore my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a case-insensitive selector this question might be helpful:

[Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)