# Where to place jQuery.expr code? 

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a solution to have a case-insensitive version of the `:contains` selector in jQuery. I found these two posts here on Stack Overflow:

[Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)
[How do I make jQuery Contains case insensitive, including jQuery 1.8+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive)

So basically the solution is this:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

My only question is how do I use this? Where to I specify this piece of code?
I'm loading jQuery in my header and afterwards I load my script.js file where I have my DOM ready function declared. I put this piece of code outside the DOM ready function but it doesn't change anything in the behaviour of the `:contains` selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put this piece of code after loading jquery, you will have one contains and one (case-insensitive) icontains selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
        // case insensitive version of :contains
        icontains: function(a,i,m){
            return (a.textContent||a.innerText||jQuery(a).text()||"").
                toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase())>=0;
        }
    });
```