# jQuery Character search

Tags: jquery, search

I want change the background color of limited character in a string

I have text box and string, I want to change the background-color of the string from the text box
Using Jquery
eg:

When I enter the text 'char' in the text box i need to change all 'char' and 'CHAR' text listed ul

```
<ul class="brows_all_cat"> 

<li><a> My sample character1  </a></li>
<li><a> My sample CHARACTER2  </a></li>
<li><a> My sample character3  </a></li>
<li><a> My sample character4  </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a variable to store entered phrase:

   var word = '';
2. Write an event handler

   $(document).on('keypress', highlight);
3. Now implement `hightlight` function:

   ```
   function highlight(event) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   1. Add pressed key to phrase:

      ```
      word += String.fromCharCode(event.which);
      ```
   2. Extract innerText from all `<a>` elements, then add hightlights, by wrapping phrase with an `<span>` element

      ```
      $('li>a').each(function() {
          var element = $(this);
          var text = element.text();
          text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + word + ')', 'ig'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
          element.html(text);
      });
      ```
4. Add a style to `.highlight` selector:

   ```
   <style>
       span.highlight {
           color: red;
       }
   </style>
   ```

By combining all code, it should be like below:

```
var word = '';

function highlight(event) {
    word += String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    $('li>a').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var text = element.text();
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + word + ')', 'ig'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
        element.html(text);
    });
}

$(document).on('keypress', 'highlight');
```

There is still one problem left, when would be the phrase be cleared, after a certain time that document doesn't receive any keypress event, or is there any other strategy?

Comment: deleted my answer, cause this one is far more accurate, informative and just plain awesome ;)

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean the [`.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, especially [making it case-INsensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196683/575527)

```
//make :contains() case insensitive
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) { 
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
};

//then 

var elementsThatHaveText = $('.brows_all_cat a:contains("'+text_you_need+'")');
```