# jQuery selector for a checkbox that contains certain text in its name attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a selector in jQuery that select all inputs that are checkboxes and their name contains a specific word like "top" or "Top".  Having trouble b/c its selecting other checkboxes.

Is it possible to use something like:

```
$("input[name*='top'] type:checkbox").each etc?

Top 1<input type="checkbox" name="Top1" /><br />
Top 2<input type="checkbox" name="Top2" /><br />
Top 3<input type="checkbox" name="Top3" /><br />
Top 4<input type="checkbox" name="Top4" /><br />

Bottom 1<input type="checkbox" name="Bottom1" /><br />
Bottom 2<input type="checkbox" name="Bottom1" /><br />
Bottom 3<input type="checkbox" name="Bottom1" /><br />
Bottom 4<input type="checkbox" name="Bottom1" /><br />
```

I only want to select the check boxes which contian the word "top" in its name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were close...

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name^='Top']").each()
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X7e67/)

Comment: I *think* these selectors are case sensitive, aren't they?

Comment: So I just add two of the box selectors?  And ^='Top' translates to Top or top?

Comment: @MarkK just another note, for case insensitive you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: @RetroCoder It is case-sensitive. If you write `^='Top'`, it will match `Top` but not `top`.

Comment: @bažmegakapa demo always helps thanks NOTE: *='Top' is case-sensitive as well (I didn't know that)

Answer (score 6):

you can use `start with` selector:

```
$("input[name^='Top']")
```

or:

```
$("input[name^='Top']:checkbox")
```

Comment: Please note that `:checkbox` is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you could combine the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector and the [attribute-contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("input:checkbox[name*='top']").each();
```

Not sure if it needs to be case insensitive, in that case you could have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive).

**Update:**

As bažmegakapa points out in his comment, `:checkbox` selector is deprecated according to the documentation. Therefor it is probably better to use:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name*='top']").each();
```

Comment: From the manual: `The bare $(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('*:checkbox'), so $('input:checkbox') should be used instead.`

Comment: And I upvoted. Also, `:checkbox` is deprecated so it might be better to use `[type="checkbox"]`.