# How to group table rows and filter the groups with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `<tbody>` to group table rows. My table looks like this:

```
<label for="kwd_search">Search:</label> <input type="text" id="kwd_search" value=""/>

<br /><br />

<table id="indberetningstable" style="text-align: center; border: solid; align: center">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Valgsted</th>
            <th>Parti</th>
            <th>Stemmer</th>
            <th>Gem</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Idrætshuset</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>A          - Socialdemokraterne</td>
                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 175px"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Gem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>B          - Det Radikale Venstre</td>
                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 175px"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Gem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>C          - Det Konservative Folkeparti</td>
                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 175px"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Gem"></td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Strandvejsskolen</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>A          - Socialdemokraterne</td>
                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 175px"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Gem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>B          - Det Radikale Venstre</td>
                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 175px"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Gem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>C          - Det Konservative Folkeparti</td>
                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 175px"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Gem"></td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>

</table>​
```

You can see an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zDA7n/

How is it possible to filter the table, so that when i write a search string in the `"kwd_search"` input field, it will hide everything but the `<tbody>` group that contains the search-text in it's first  column (Valgsted) ?

Comment: I thought an HTML table was only supposed to have one `tbody`. [Apparently I was wrong](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html).

Comment: I got the idea from here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?725545-Grouping-lt-tr-gt-table-rows

Comment: Just cause you can do it doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: I guess i could perhaps group the rows with a custom data-attribute, but i still dont know how to filter it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector (note: this is case-sensitive):

```
$('#kwd_search').on('change',function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val());
    $('#indberetningstable tbody').show();
    if (val) {
        $('#indberetningstable tbody:not(:contains("'+val+'"))').hide();
    };
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pEfSF/

For a case-insensitive version, you'll need to [implement a custom version of the `:contains` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2196641/901048).

Comment: Thanks alot ! Seems to work. Only problem is, when i write an "S" for the second tbody, it doesn't filter, unless i write "St" - any idea why?

Comment: Would it be possible to make this functio not case sensitive?
I tried the following, but doesnt work quite well when searching for "st": $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        'contains': function (elem, i, match, array) {
            return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }
    });

Comment: Just found it it is because it looks in all columns, and there are other columns that contain "S" or "str" :/ - Any way to make it search only in the first td?