# jQuery: Show only content which contains search values

Tags: jquery, search

I want to show only divs that contains the entered search values.
So if I type `upload login` in the Searchbox it should show only Question 1 and Question 3.

**Note**: It should work with multiple search input values(like in the example: should search for value `upload` AND `login` and show the divs which contains this values).

**Note 2**: It should also show Question 1 and Question 3 if the search input is like this: `upl log`

**Note 3**: Not case sensitiv. So `upload` should filter the div(Question 1) with content `Upload`.

This is what i got:

```
<section id="content">
<div id="search-block">
    <input type="text" id="inpSearch" placeholder="Search.." />
</div>
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Question 1</h1>
        <p>Harry Markus Upload</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Question 2</h1>
        <p>Registration Append August Download</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Question 3</h1>
        <p>Login July Dad</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#inpSearch').keyup(function(){
    var sSearch = this.value;
    $('section#content > div:not(:first-child)').hide();
    $('section#content > div:contains("' + sSearch + '"):not(:first-child)').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have two problems.

1. You need to use case insensitive jQuery :contains selector. For eg: If you search for `upload` or `Upload` it should fetch results.

**CODE:**

```
 jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
             return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
                 .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
           };
           jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
             return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
                 .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
           };
```

SOURCE: [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

2.Split the search string and parse using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like:

**CODE:**

```
    $('#inpSearch').keyup(function(){
    var sSearch = this.value;
    sSearch = sSearch.split(" ");
    $('section#content > div:not(:first-child)').hide();
    $.each(sSearch, function(i){
    $('section#content > div:contains("' + sSearch[i] + '"):not(:first-child)').show();
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qxZme/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow, almost perfect.. just one little issue. When I enter for example `upl `, then it shows all of the question. I think it's because he's filtering the blank space too.

Comment: I couldn't able to replicate in fiddle. could you check once in fiddle?

Comment: It's working in the fiddle.. I really just copied the code like a newbie and paste it in my script. I just found out when I type `upl ` the split function makes 2 array values.

Comment: Got it. I just put this before the `:contains` selector: `if(sSearch[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $('#content div').not("#search-block").hide();
$('#inpSearch').on('keyup',function(){
    $('#content div').not("#search-block").hide();
    var val = this.value;
    val = val.split(" ");
    var contains="";
    for(var i = 0; i < val.length;i++){
        contains.length >0?contains+=",div":"";
        contains+=":contains('"+val[i]+"')";
    }
    $('#content div'+contains).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KYjfk/5/)

For case sensitive take a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8)

Comment: @Alvaro works for me, i'm using chrome. Remember it is case sensitive

Comment: That is very weird, i have no idea why because it's working completly fine for me. I've tested on 2 different computers now works fine

Comment: tested on 30.0.1599.28 (Officiell version 221063) beta-m and 29.0.1547.66 (Officiell version 220848) m

Comment: Type `fasdfasdfsadfa`. You shouldn't get any result and all still visible.

Comment: It also fails when typing `Upload` and deleting it all again.

Comment: Now i see what you mean, i'll fix it, tyty :)