# searching in LI using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am searching in list of 500 li's. using following code. but facing two problems. one when i press backspace very fastly after typing something, it is not captured. and also searching is case sensitive which i dont want. please suggest improvements in below code :

```
$('#find_question').bind("keyup", function() {
    searchWord = $(this).val();
    console.log("input length",searchWord);
    if (searchWord.length >= 0) {

        $('#leftSection li').each(function(i, data) {
            text = $(this).text();
            if (text.match(RegExp(searchWord, 'i')))
                $(this).show();

            else
                $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

The containsIgnoreCase comes from [How do I make jQuery Contains case insensitive, including jQuery 1.8+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8)

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8NJUw/)

```
 $.expr[':'].containsIgnoreCase = function (n, i, m) {
    return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
 };

$function() {
  $('#find_question').on("keyup", function() {
    searchWord = $(this).val();
    $('#leftSection li').hide();
    if (searchWord.length >= 0) {
      $('#leftSection li:containsIgnoreCase("'+searchWord+'")').show();
    }
  });
});
```