# Isotope.js filtering for html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Is isotope filtering working for HTML Tables? What I want to do is filter using a search form, so my contacts list will be filtered based on the value of the search box . Here is my sample fiddle for this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/HEdc2/3/) and my sample code for isotope:

```
var $container = $('.rm-data').isotope({
    // options
});
$('#search').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var query = $('#search').val();
        $container.isotope({
            filter: query
        });
        console.log(query);

    }
});
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think the isotope.js plugin will work on HTML tables... I may be wrong. I'd filter the table the old fashioned way, hand code it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isotope seems to mess up the table formatting, but it seems to work ok.  You were very close to being able to match based on names.

```
<tbody="rm-data">
```

Needs to be

```
<tbody class="rm-data">
```

And then add a dot in front of your query so it will filter on class names

```
$container.isotope({ filter: "."+query });
```

And then it works.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HEdc2/4/

However if you're looking to be able to search the contents of any cell in the table, you'll need a fancier filter.

```
$('#search').on('keypress',function(e){
   if(e.which == 13){
       var query = $('#search').val();
       query = "tr:contains("+query+")";
       $container.isotope({ filter: query });
       console.log(query);

   }
});
```

Seems to do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/HEdc2/5/

However, jQuery's `:contains()` selector is case sensitive, so if you want a case insensitive search you'll have to to figure something out.  Answers to this question may help: [How do I make jQuery Contains case insensitive, including jQuery 1.8+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8)

Comment: is it necessary to add the isotope class or does it have conflict with a particular jquery im using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: Thanks the :contains selector really helped :)