# Search for value using :contains and ignore case

Tags: jquery

I've got input field which allows to search for values inside div blocks.
For now, I'm using following construction:

```
var $this = $('.multiple-selector-wrapper');

$('.ms-search').keyup(function(event){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $this.find('.multiple-selector-table-row').hide();
    $this.find('.ms-column:contains("' + value + '")').parents('.multiple-selector-table-row').show();      
});
```

Problem is, search will always perform strict value case. Is it possible to ignore case for search?

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6e5/1/

Comment: That answer apparently doesn't work in recent versions of jQuery. I found this as a newer answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8/2196683#2196683

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector