# How to check if element contains string after converting everything to lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a simple input field to search through a list on my website using this code:

```
$('#f-search').keyup(function() {
    var q = $('#f-search').val().toLowerCase();
    $("#f-list .f // toLowerCase // :contains('q')").css('border-color', '#900');
});
```

My problem is that the list elements (`.f`) contain unpredictable capital letters, so in order to accurately check it against the input I need to convert it to lower case, but I don't know how to do that and then use `:contains`. For example, if one `.f` contains "WoWoWoWoWzzzziees" but the user typed "wow", it wouldn't be a match with my current code, but I'd like it to be.

Comment: Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
$("#f-list .f").filter(function() {
  return $(this)
         .text() // or .html() or .val(), depends on the element type
         .toLowerCase()
         .indexOf(q) != -1;
}).css('border-color', '#900');
```

which compares the text inside your elements selected by `"#f-list .f"` and, if they contain what is in the `q` variable, they get the css modification applied.

**EDIT:**

If you also want the list to be reset each time, you can do this:

```
$("#f-list .f").css('border-color', 'WHATEVER IT WAS').filter(function() {
  return $(this)
         .text() // or .html() or .val(), depends on the element type
         .toLowerCase()
         .indexOf(q) != -1;
}).css('border-color', '#900');
```

For better performance you could cache your list like this:

```
var f_list = $("#f-list .f"),
    f_search = $('#f-search');

f_search.keyup(function() {
    var q = f_search.val().toLowerCase();
    f_list.css('border-color', 'WHATEVER IT WAS').filter(function() {
      return $(this)
             .text() // or .html() or .val(), depends on the element type
             .toLowerCase()
             .indexOf(q) != -1;
    }).css('border-color', '#900');
});
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can go as far as creating your own custom `:contains` selector in jQuery:

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/):

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
    return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
```

And use it like this (please note the new selector is `:Contains` with uppercase C):

```
$("#f-list .f:Contains('q')").css('border-color', '#900');
```