# Find (case insensitive) Words on an external Website and count them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this snippet to find and count words on an external Website. How can I search case insensitive? For e.g.: Test, test or TEST - everything counts? I use the current jQuery-Version. Thank you four your tips.

```
    function keyWordSearch() {
    var kWord = jQuery('#keywords').val();
    var webSite = jQuery('#urls').val();
    var spanSelector = "span:contains(" + kWord + ")";

    $.ajax({
        url : webSite,
        success : function(data) {
            //check in span//
            spanKeyword = 0;
            var message = $('<div/>').append(data).find(spanSelector).each(function() {
                spanKeyword += parseInt($(this).text().split(kWord).length - 1);
            });
            alert('span ' + spanKeyword);

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8

Comment: Keep in mind you only search inside `<span>` elements, whereas text might as well be inside a `<div>`, `<p>` (such as your question) or something else. So you will be missing a lot of text.

Comment: Your right, but I search additional for p, h1, h2, ... Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my new answer:

```
$.ajax({
        url : webSite,
        success : function(data) {
            //check in span//
            var spanKeyword = 0;
            var regExp = new RegExp("(^|\\W)" + kWord + "(\\W|$)", "gi");
            jQuery(data).find("span").each(function(){
              var data = jQuery(this).text();
              spanKeyword += data.match(regExp).length;
            });
            alert('span ' + spanKeyword);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are my hero Mindastic. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If case is immaterial why arent you using .toLowerCase() on your text?

```
spanKeyword += parseInt($(this).text().toLowerCase().split(kWord).length - 1);
```

or to make your keyword case insentive

```
var kWord = jQuery('#keywords').val().toLowerCase();
```

considering that kWord is string

Comment: I´ve tried to this. But, If I make both case insentive, it finds noting - it returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using a regular expression?

You could probably do:

```
$.ajax({
    url : webSite,
    success : function(data) {
        //check in span//
        var regExp = new RegExp("(^|\\W)" + kWord + "(\\W|$)", "gi");

        spanKeyword = data.match(regExp).length;

        alert('span ' + spanKeyword);

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, the problem is, it ignores to search only in spans

Comment: Ok, in that case, you can do what i will post in another answer (to be able to add code).