# how to fix search in <LI>where users can use caps or lowercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is JavaScript I'm using for search query there is bug i have found which is issue with letter being caps or lower case. If the letters in list are lower case then it only searches for lower case but if you were to turn the caps on it doesn't find anything. Below are the codes i'm using any help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<input type='search' id='search' placeholder='search'>
<ul>
    <li>example 1</li>
    <li>example 2</li>
    <li>example 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var search = $("#search");
var listItems = $("li");
search.on("keyup", function () {
    var terms = search.val();
    if (terms == '') {
        listItems.show();
    } else {
        listItems.hide();
        $("li:contains('" + terms + "')").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make jQuery Contains case insensitive, including jQuery 1.8+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite existing jquery `contains`:

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

var search = $("#search");
var listItems = $("li");
search.on("keyup", function () {
    var terms = search.val();
    if (terms == '') {
        listItems.show();
    } else {
        listItems.hide();
        $("li:contains('" + terms + "')").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' id='search' placeholder='search'>
<ul>
    <li>example 1</li>
    <li>example 2</li>
    <li>example 3</li>
</ul>
```

Or create a new one:

```js
    jQuery.expr[':'].ncontains = function(a, i, m) {
      return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
          .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };



var search = $("#search");
var listItems = $("li");
search.on("keyup", function () {
    var terms = search.val();
    if (terms == '') {
        listItems.show();
    } else {
        listItems.hide();
        $("li:ncontains('" + terms + "')").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' id='search' placeholder='search'>
<ul>
    <li>example 1</li>
    <li>example 2</li>
    <li>example 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks alex it worked :) is there better way to improve the search in list?

Comment: There are lot search filters out there. For example take a look here http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-make-search-input-to-filter-through-list-using-jquery_642.html but i think this one is ok too :)

Comment: I would personally recommend using `icontains` as the name.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `terms` lowercase and then search.

```
var terms = search.val().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```
//elsewhere case may vary but here only case is ignored
$("li:contains('" + terms.toLowerCase() + "')").show();
```

While you consider using this  elsewhere in your code:

```
//elsewhere case is ignored by transforming lowercase terms to search for
var terms = search.val().toLowerCase();
```