# Search Engine with jQuery :contains()

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, search, contains

I'm working on a project that requires a simple search engine.
The idea is not to use plugins like "autocomplete" and "jquery ui" but to exploit the ":contains()" jQuery method.

Now, this function does exactly what I'm talking about.

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){

    var v = $(this).val();

    $('.element').hide();
    $(".element:contains('"+v+"')").show();


});
```

The problem is,
if a term is called "Foo" and I searching for "foo", the search engine do not returns any results... rightly.
So I ask you if there is a way to solve this problem... using only jQuery.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8

Comment: FYI, `:contains()` isn't a jQuery method but a CSS pseudo class selector