# Hide the div elements if not including specific keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I have seen a brunch of solution about how to show/hide the div which do not contains(or contains) specific keywords but none of them do help.**

So far I  have done some codes like this:

```
<div class="media">Title : orange</div>
<div class="media">this is something about orangessss yolo</div>
<div class="media">Title : apple</div>
<div class="media">this is something about apple yolo</div>

<button id="filter">test</button>
```

And I have a method to fliter the elements:

```
        var KeywordArr = ["orange","orangessss"];

$('#filter').click(function () {  
        var key = $(".media"); 
        var word= key.find(".media").html();
            if(!word && word.toLowerCase().match([KeywordArr])) {
            $(".media").css("display", "none");
        }
});
```

These codes suppose to add "display:none" to every **"media"** class which does not contains any keywords included in the array. But it's not working as my exception.

So how can I hide all the elements when the "< div"> do not have the value contain in keywordArr?

**Solution:**

```
 $('#filter').click(function () {  

            var elems = $(".media");
            var KeywordArr = ["orange", "orangessss"];
            var res = $();
            for (var i = 0; i < KeywordArr.length; i++) {
              res = res.add(elems.filter(":contains('" + KeywordArr[i] + "')"));
            }
            elems.not(res).hide();

    });
```

Comment: You have a typo in button id.

Comment: You are not looking at individual instances and you are also trying to look inside `.media` for `.media`

Comment: Thanks, will correct it now. Maybe i should take some rest .

Comment: I am scanning through every 'media class', because we generate the json contents depends on a for loop in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `:contains()` selector at this context,

```
var elems = $(".media");
var KeywordArr = ["orange", "orangessss"];
var res = $();

for (var i = 0; i < KeywordArr.length; i++) {
  res = res.add(elems.filter(":contains('" + KeywordArr[i] + "')"));
}

elems.not(res).hide();
```

Also note that `contains` selector is case sensitive.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nnz7woya/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it seem working now, but i need to do some modification, by the way am i able to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: @anson920520 That is how the api was written. But you can override its behavior. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code more declarative you can use array `foreach`. also make sure to keep you variable names all lowercase.

```
var elems = $(".media");
var keywordArr = ["orange", "orangessss"];
var res = $();

keywordArr.forEach(function(keyword){
    res = res.add(elems.filter(":contains('" + keyword + "')"));
});

elems.not(res).hide();
```

Also if you can write the Same code with ES6 Template literals, here is a link to [Demo](http://jsbin.com/junabu/edit?js,output)

```
const elems = $(".media");
const keywordArr = ["orange", "orangessss"];
let res = $();

keywordArr.forEach(
    (keyword) => res = res.add(elems.filter(`:contains(${keyword})`))
);

elems.not(res).hide();
```