# passing arguments to custom filter fn in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
     1. jQuery.expr[':'].aFilter =
        function(elem, index, match){

                return true; // Return true/false as per need

        };

        $('div.red').filter(':aFilter').doSomething();
```

i want pass some custom arguments to "jQuery.expr[':'].aFilter" function, is it possible to do it

Comment: what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: i want pass some custom arguments to "jQuery.expr[':'].aFilter" function, is it possible to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case if someone did `$('div.red').filter(':aFilter(textHere)')` You would use `match[3]` in your function to do what you wanted with the `textHere` string.

Here's an example I use for case-insentitive contains search:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) { 
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
};
```

The use is:  `$(":Contains(Text To Match)");`
In this case `m[3]` ("Text To Match") is the passed param I care about.

[You can find a full list of the parameters in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector/190183#190183)

Comment: i was looking for something like this only, 
i think we cannot pass an object to filter fn as third paramneter
still this code solved my problem thanx.