# jQgrid search a value on the grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have to search a value contained in a jQGrid and when found it, I have to delete the row.

How I can scan the rows of the grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I understand your question you work with local grids and want to search for text on the current page of jqGrid. In the case you can use jQuery. The construct like

```
$("#list > tbody > tr td:contains('" + str + "')").parent();
```

can be used to find all rows contain string `str` (case sensitive). To delete the row you can use [delRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method. To make case insensitive search with jQuery there are different methods. One on the simplest is to use `RegEx`. Another method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector).

You can see a small demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchPerJQuery.htm) which demonstrate both case sensitive and case insensitive data seraching.

**Updated**: Instead of the usage of `parent()` method one can also use `:has` filter:

```
$("#list > tbody > tr:has(td:contains('" + str + "'))");
```

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791020/how-to-search-for-a-row-and-then-select-it-in-jqgrid/3798151#3798151) on the close question could be also interesting for you.

**Remark**: Be careful if you use `rownumbers: true` option because all above search constructs search **also in column 'rn' contains row numbers**. So if you type 3 in the input field the third row will be deleted.