# How to search for a row and then select it in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a scenario where in I have to select a row in jqGrid programatically.

From a function I will have a value of a column which is available in jqGrid and based on passed in column's value I have to search in jqGrid and when it finds a record match I have to select that row.

Not sure how to achieve this using jQuery for my jqGrid.

Update:

The solution you mentioned searches for 3rd column (case insensitive). I was wondering is there any way to search in any column in grid (including hidden colums as well) using regext i.e. case insensitive search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is close to the other question which I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781900/jqgrid-search-a-value-on-the-grid/3783086#3783086) recently. The distinguish is that you want to search for a selected column. For case-sensitive searching you can use following code

```
var index = 3;
var str = 'b';
$("#list > tbody > tr > td:nth-child("+index+"):contains('" + str + "')").parent();
```

For case-insensitive searching the code could look like

```
var index = 3;
var str = 'b';
var cells = $("#list > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)").filter(function() {
                return re.test( $(this).text());
            });
var rows = cells.parent();
```

It is important to take in consideration that jqGrid has sometimes additional columns before the columns declared in the `colModel`. This is 'rn' column contains row numbers. It exists if you use `rownumbers: true` option of jqGrid. In you use the option `multiselect: true` there are also 'cb' column with check-boxes. You can hide the column with respect of `$('#list').jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb');`, but you should calculate there also. In general you should calculate all hidden columns.

You can see all live in the following small [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchPerJQueryAndSelect.htm).

Comment: Is any way to search and get exact matchs? not just contains ?!

Comment: You can use `filter` for exact matching too.