# How do I edit a jqgrid from javascript

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid that has several columns including a checkbox column that indicates if an item is selected.

Underneath that I have a dropdown menu and a text box.  The idea is that each item in the dropdown menu is a column in the jqgrid.  Then all I need to do is modified all of the checked rows with the contents of the text box for that column.  So a quick mass update mechanism if you will.

The problem is, is that I can't figure out how to update a specific cell.  Any tips or documentation that can help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example [setRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data) (see [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)) or [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to update the data in the grid. The functions `getCol`, `getCell` or `getRowData` could help you the examine the row data. Another old answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791020/how-to-search-for-a-row-and-then-select-it-in-jqgrid/3798151#3798151) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781900/jqgrid-search-a-value-on-the-grid/3783086#3783086) could be helpful if you decide to search data in the grid with respect of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "answer" I came up with to my problem.  I wanted to edit only rows that were editable.  Using setCell would overwrite my editable field with a non-editable one.  So I looked at the HTML for a given row while it is in the edit state and passed that into the 'setCell' method.  It feels 'hackish' though and if someone knows a better way, I'm all ears.