# JQuery JqGrid: How to filter grid without using local and calling server to filter

Tags: jquery, filter, jqgrid, local

I have a JqGrid that's populated by a server-side Spring-powered data. I don't use local property in my JqGrid. Whenever I search, it calls the server-side to call the specified url in the JqGrid configuration. That's good.

But what if I just want to filter out the existing data that the grid is showing? Assuming the grid is showing 50 records (let's ignore paging or hypothetically think that there are 10 more remaining pages). How do I search this 50 records for a particular entry without calling the server-side.

Now that I'm able to search. The grid should be able to filter out and show only those items I wanna see.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781900/jqgrid-search-a-value-on-the-grid/3783086#3783086) which use pure searching with respect of `jQuery`. This way should work in your environment.

To be sure how `delRowData` work read in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) used in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchPerJQuery.htm) from the answer:

> delRowData Deletes the row with the id
>   = rowid. This operation does not delete data from the server.

So at the next reload of the grid with the data from the server you will see original data.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've actually read that post which you mentioned. I was thinking that there's a built-in function in JqGrid. Anyway, the  JQuery way is also acceptable.