# Writing jQuery selector case-insensitive version

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using following line and I would like to make it case-insensitive:

```
var matches = $(this).find('div > span > div#id_to_find[attributeName ^= "filter"]');
if (matches.length > 0) {
}
```

My question is that how can I make the selector `^=` to be case-insensitive? Maybe changing to filter and then some regexp?

Comment: I thing here is the answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do a case-insensitive attribute selection, you need to write a custom selector function.

```
$.expr[':'].iAttrStart = function(obj, params, meta, stack) {
    var opts = meta[3].match(/(.*)\s*,\s*(.*)/);
    return (opts[1] in obj) && (obj[opts[1]].toLowerCase().indexOf(opts[2].toLowerCase()) === 0);
};
```

You can use this like this:

```
$('input:iAttrStart(type, r)')
```

This will match any `input` elements whose `type` attribute begins with `R` or `r` (so it would match `RADIO`, `radio`, `RESET` or `reset`).  This is a pretty silly example, but it should do what you need.

---

Re the comment that the function is hard to understand, I'll explain it a little.

```
$.expr[':'].iAttrStart = function(obj, params, meta, stack) {
```

This is the standard signature for creating custom selectors.

```
var opts = meta[3].match(/(.*)\s*,\s*(.*)/);
```

`meta` is an array of details about the call.  `meta[3]` is the string passed as the parameter.  In my example, this is `type, r`.  The regex matches `type` and `r` separately.

```
return (opts[1] in obj) && (obj[opts[1]].toLowerCase().indexOf(opts[2].toLowerCase()) === 0);
```

Return if both these are true:

1. The requested attribute exists on this object (`opts[1] in obj`)
2. The search term (changed to lower-case) is found at the very beginning of the element's attribute value, also changed to lower case.

I could have made this easier to read using jQuery syntax rather than native JS syntax, but that would have meant reduced performance.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Took little bit time to figure out what function does, but now when I understand it's kinda nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/creating-a-custom-jquery-selector/

What you have to do is to create a custom jquery selector:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    exactIgnoreCase: "(a.textContent||a.innerText||jQuery(a).text()||'').toLowerCase() == (m[3]).toLowerCase()"
});
```

And then just use it:

```
$("#detail select.fields option:exactIgnoreCase(" + q.val() + "):first");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I'll use lonesomeday's answer this time

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight problem when using lonesomeday's answer.

To reproduce the error, try this:
HTML tag on page is a common Facebook meta tag:

```
<meta content="Title of og tag" property="og:title" />
```

Selector:

```
$('meta:attrCaseInsensitive(property, og:site_name)')
```

This will not work. The reason is because when the selector code gets to the statement `(opts[1] in obj)` 
it will execute `("property" in obj)` which returns false. (I don't know why)

To fix this problem, I just changed the last line to use jQuery's attr() method

```
$.expr[':'].iAttrStart = function(obj, params, meta, stack) {
    var opts = meta[3].match(/(.*)\s*,\s*(.*)/);
    return (undefined != $(obj).attr(opts[1])) && (obj[opts[1]].toLowerCase().indexOf(opts[2].toLowerCase()) === 0)
};
```