# CSS selector case insensitive for attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, case-insensitive, selenium-webdriver

If I have an HTML element `<input type="submit" value="Search" />` a css selector needs to be case-sensitive:

`input[value='Search']` matches

`input[value='search']` does not match

**I need a solution where the case-insensitive approach works too.** I am using **Selenium 2** and **Jquery**, so answers for both are welcome.

Comment: Possibly duplicate question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967869/writing-jquery-selector-case-insensitive-version

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It now exists in CSS4, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721521/31671).

Otherwise, for jQuery, you can use...

```
$(':input[name]').filter(function() {
   return this.value.toLowerCase() == 'search';
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RRcth/).

You could also make a custom selector...

```
$.expr[':'].valueCaseInsensitive = function(node, stackIndex, properties){
     return node.value.toLowerCase() == properties[3];
};

var searchInputs = $(':input:valueCaseInsensitive("Search")');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/8UDdj/).

The custom selector is a bit of overkill if doing this once, but if you need to use it many times in your application, it may be a good idea.

#### Update

> Is it possible to have that kind of custom selector for any attribute?

Sure, check out the following example. It's a little convoluted (syntax such as `:input[value:toLowerCase="search"]` may have been more intuitive), but it works :)

```
$.expr[':'].attrCaseInsensitive = function(node, stackIndex, properties){
    var args = properties[3].split(',').map(function(arg) {
        return arg.replace(/^\s*["']|["']\s*$/g, '');  
    });
    return $(node).attr(args[0]).toLowerCase() == args[1];
};

var searchInputs = $('input:attrCaseInsensitive(value, "search")');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/pDvtK/).

You could probably use `eval()` to make that string an array, but I find doing it this way more comfortable (and you won't accidentally execute any code you place in your selector).

Instead, I am splitting the string on `,` delimiter, and then stripping whitespace, `'` and `"` either side of each array member. Note that a `,` inside a quote won't be treated literally. There is no reason one should be required literally, but you could always code against this possibility. I'll leave that up to you. :)

I don't think [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has the best browser support, so you can explictly iterate over the `args` array or [augment the `Array` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

Comment: the custom selector looks exactly like what i need. can you explain what properties[3] is?

Comment: @Alp `properties[3]` is the string passed as an argument to the custom selector (the other indexes are assorted meta data).

Comment: @alex is it possible to have that kind of custom selector for any attribute? so that all attributes like name, value, class and so on are case-insensitive?

Comment: @Alp Yes, but it gets a little messy. Let me make an update :)

Comment: A better return statement is    return typeof $(node).attr(args[0]) !== 'undefined' && $(node).attr(args[0]).toLowerCase() == args[1].toLowerCase();

Comment: @Could be, but I wouldn't use a `typeof` there as it's not necessary.

Answer (score 83):

**[CSS4 (CSS Selector Level 4)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case)** adds support for it:

```
input[value='search' i]
```

It's the "i" at the end which does the trick.

Broader adoption started mid-2016: Chrome (since v49), Firefox (from v47?), Opera and some others have it. IE not and Edge since it uses Blink. See [“Can I use”](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive)...

Comment: @Miscreant: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector/28050505#28050505 for how to get it working in your browser.

Comment: Chrome added support for this in version 49.0 (released in March 2016). Firefox will add support in version 47.0 (scheduled to be released in June 2016). Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I can confirm it working with plain Chromium Version 49.0.2623.108.

Answer (score 9):

```
input[value='Search'] matches
input[value='search' i] Also matches in latest browsers
```

Support:
version : Chrome >= 49.0, Firefox (Gecko) >= 47.0, Safari >= 9

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with selectors alone, try:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('value').toLowerCase() == 'search';
});
```

Comment: You may as well use `val()` there. Also, it appears they want an exact match, not an `indexOf()`. :)

Comment: Very true, but I used `attr()` to show you can use it for other attributes as well. Updated to exact match.