# Case-insensitive attribute-value selector with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, business-logic

I need to get the value of the `content` attribute of a certain `meta` tag.

```
var someContent = $("meta[name=someKindOfId]").attr("content");
```

is how I usually do it. For business reasons, `someKindOfId` may be `somekindofid`. It could be other combinations of cases as well. I don't know.

What is the best way to search for this meta tag? Adding an id or other identifier is out of the question.

Comment: See this post, pretty good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the jquery filter function like so

```
var meta = $('meta[name]').filter(function() {
    return this.name.toLowerCase() == 'somekindofid';
});
```

Based upon [CSS selector case insensitive for attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671238/css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes)

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/mkBvC/

Comment: Perfect. var someContent = $('meta[name]').filter(function() { return this.name.toLowerCase() == 'somekindofid'; }).attr("content");

Comment: Something I noticed with that solution Josh is that it will only return the content for 1 meta tag.  I'm not sure if you'd have multiple meta tags with the same name but here's an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/mkBvC/1/

Comment: This is a working solution, but not very reusable. Please check my jQuery expression answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Also, for case insensitive attribute *= selector:

```
$("meta[name*=someKindOfId]")
```

You can use:

```
$('meta').filter(function() {
       return (/somekindofid/i).test($(this).attr('name'));
}).attr("content")
```

Comment: Thisis like a *=, not =, but it's what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

You can reuse the case-insensitive **jQuery expression**, as shown in the snippet below (execute it to see how the first div matches, while the second does not).

```js
$.expr[':'].iAttrContains = function(node, stackIndex, properties){
    var args = properties[3].split(',').map(function(arg) {
        return arg.replace(/^\s*["']|["']\s*$/g, '');  
    });
    if ($(node).attr(args[0])) {
        //exact match:
        return $(node).attr(args[0]).toLowerCase() == args[1].toLowerCase();
        //if you actually prefer a "contains" behavior:
        //return -1 !== $(node).attr(args[0]).toLowerCase().indexOf(args[1].toLowerCase());
    }
};

$("div:iAttrContains('data-name', 'test')").addClass('matched');
```

```css
div{background:red;}
div.matched{background:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-name="This is a test">First div</div>
<div data-name="This is a div">Second div</div>
```