# jQuery select by boolean data attribute

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I've got this line of code:

```
$(selector).find(":input[data-val=true]")
```

This will **correctly** select elements like this

```
<input type='number' data-val='true' />
```

But this will **NOT** select elements with alternate casing, like so: *(note the capital T)*

```
<input type='number' data-val='True' />
```

Besides putting in multiple selectors for different casing, what is a good way to make sure the selector returns the elements with the correct boolean value in it (even though it's a string"

---

FYI, the casing variance occurs due to my MVC application when I set the vlaue to an actual boolean, it will capialize this when it gets converted to a string :(

```
@Html.TextBox("quoteNumber", "", new { type = "number", data_val = true, data_val_required = "You must enter a quote number!" })
```

Comment: You probably have to use `.filter()` then and normalize the attribute value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case-insensitive attribute-value selector with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755722/case-insensitive-attribute-value-selector-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.filter` method with a regexp:

```
$(selector).find(":input").filter(function(){
    return /true/i.test($(this).attr("data-val"));
});
```

Comment: Awesome, that works great.  Maybe even `return /true/i.test($(this).data("val"));` instead?

Comment: @Chris Barr Well, if you used that, you would be comparing against a boolean value instead of a string value. jQuery automatically converts `"true"` in a data attribute to boolean `true`, but it doesn't convert `"True"` to a boolean `true`.

Answer (score 1):

in this case if you want to have a single jquery selector, you should use a REGEX for the boolean value :) it looks a bit hackish but it can solve your problem.