# How does one match an element in jQuery without needing to match case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with some navigation and I'm trying to highlight the link if that's the page we're on.  It works almost quite well just like this:

```
function highlightPageInNav() {
        // Get file name.
        var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        // Build selector.
        var attrSelector = "a[href='" + filename + "']";
        // Set class of li to "current".
        $("#nav ul li").has(attrSelector).addClass("current");
}
```

The problem is that the anchors in my navigation say, for example, "CreateUser.aspx", but the script won't match that if the current URL contains "createuser.aspx".

I've tried several other ideas, including using the following to replace part of the script above.  I convert the filename toLowerCase() and then try to match it to the href .toLowerCase() and those alerts show me what I expect, but the `$(this).addClass("current");` doesn't actually do anything -- most likely, I guess, because `$(this)` no longer applies to the element I'm trying to modify.

```
$("#nav ul li a").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
    hrefLowerCase = $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase();
    alert(hrefLowerCase);
    if (filename == hrefLowerCase) {
        alert("found one!");
        $(this).addClass("current");  // This is where it stops doing what I desire.
    }
});
```

So, if someone can show me how to very simply make my script match both "CreateUser.aspx" and "createuser.aspx", that would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755722/case-insensitive-attribute-value-selector-with-jquery

Comment: You can try storing this as a variable in each loop and later make calls to this variable instead of "this".

Comment: Trying these out.  Thanks!  I seriously googled for a while for this and didn't see these questions already existing.

Comment: Are you trying to add the class to the `<a>` tag or to the `<li>` tag

Comment: Trying to add the class to the li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected DGS's answer a little bit to make it work.

```
var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).toLowerCase();
$('#nav ul li a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() === filename) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    }
});
```

It should add class current to **li** tag, not to **anchor**.

Other way as suggested is to use filter:

```
var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).toLowerCase();
$('#nav ul li a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() === filename;
}).parent().addClass('current');
```

Comment: That does it!  And as a result of asking this question, I know about the jQuery filter function.  Thanks, guys!

Comment: Btw, I don't think it's the best idea to do it like you want it to be done. It is because for example if your address looks like that:
`CreateUser.aspx#`, or `CreateUser.aspx?c=1234` then it won't match. It's much better to check the file you are in server-side

Comment: Good call.  I'm trying to rely less on server-side code than I usually do (it's a learning thing for me) and more on JavaScript, so I could just remove those characters: `filename = filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf("#"));`  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Btw, remember that `this.href` is not the same as `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);    
$('#nav ul li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href.toLowerCase() == filename;
}).addClass('current');
```

Comment: If you'll indulge me one question: I've attempted to combine your idea and a fiddle from another post, but it's not appearing to have any effect.  

    $("#nav ul li a[href]").filter(function () {
        return this.href.toLowerCase() == filename;
    }).parent().addClass("current");