# Case-insensitive attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, hyperlink, substring

I have a function that selects all `<a>` with `href` that contains `sun`:

```
jQuery('a[href*="sun"]').each(function(i, el) {
    alert(el);
});
```

How to make it case insensitive (contains substring `sUN` or `sun` or `SuN` etc)?
Checked [Case-insensitive attribute-value selector with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755722/case-insensitive-attribute-value-selector-with-jquery) but with no luck for this question.

Comment: *"Checked [Case-insensitive attribute-value selector with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755722/case-insensitive-attribute-value-selector-with-jquery) but with no luck for this question."* Huh? The accepted answer there is **exactly** how you do this.

Comment: That answer checks for equality, you should use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method after `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Would anybody help to write it in one string instead of asking for closing this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use a custom filter:

```
$('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().indexOf('sun') >-1;
})
```

Comment: OP is using Attribute Contains selector.

Comment: @BlackSheep modified my answer to work with the contains.

Answer (score 0):

And here is my answer on my question:

```
$('a[href]').filter(function() {return this.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("sun") >=0 ;}).each(function(i, el) {
    alert(el);
});
```

Comment: Still unclear about possible duplicate if the answers are really different - there were no "filter" and "each" all together.