# jquery Case Insensitive find method by data

Tags: jquery, html

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/y790z6zq/

I want to make a case insensitive search based on data attributes using find method of jquery.

Here is the HTML :

```
    <body>
    <div class="main">
     <div> 
        <p data-Col="MyVal"> hkjhkjh</p>
     </div>
     <div  data-Col="MyVAl"> some more text
     </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div  data-Col="myval"> some more text
         </div>        
        <div > 
            <p data-Col="myval"> some more nesting</p>
         </div>        
    </div>
</body>
```

& the script:

```
var searchValue ="myval";

$(".main").find("[data-Col='" + searchValue + "']").css("background-color","red");
```

I could set color to the last div (where case matches) but others are not getting selected.

Please Help..
Thanks in advance..

**Edit :** 
I also tried below script but it did not work..

```
$(".main").filter(function() {    
    return this.data("Col").toLowerCase() == searchValue.toLowerCase();
}).css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755722/case-insensitive-attribute-value-selector-with-jquery

Comment: you can use `$(".main").find("[data-Col='" + searchValue + "']").last().css("background-color","red");`

Comment: You need to do $(".main div").filter(....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your most recent attempt is nearly there, only you are attempting to filter `.main` when you really want to filter the paragraphs inside, first find them, then filter them.

Also are trying to call `.data()` on a DOM element, when you should be first creating a jQuery object out of it:

```
$(".main").find('[data-Col]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-Col').toLowerCase() == searchValue.toLowerCase();
}).css("background-color","red");
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y790z6zq/7/)

There is no case insensitive attribute selector. (*yet*).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var searchValue ="myval";

$(".main [data-Col]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-Col").toLowerCase() == searchValue.toLowerCase();
}).css("background-color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for achieve this.

```
$('.main').find('[data-col]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-col').toLowerCase().indexOf('myval') > -1;
});
```

Another way to use OR operator in selectors if you sure about the value constant e.g.

```
$('[data-col="myval"],[data-col="myVAl"], [data-col="MYVAL"]');
```