# Case insensitive jQuery search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have had some help on a Jquery script which creates a searchable filter,  The  code can be seen here:

```
$('#search-keyword').on( "keyup", function(){
    if($(this).val()){
        var input = $(this).val();
        $(".filter").hide();
        $("div[data-destination*='"+ input +"']").show();
        if(!$('.filter:visible').get(0)){
            $(".filter").show();
        }
    }else{
        $(".filter").show();
    }
});
```

The trouble is, if there is the word “How” with an upper case “H” and I search “h”, it wont find it. How can I make this script case insensitive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case-insensitive attribute-value selector with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755722/case-insensitive-attribute-value-selector-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive jQuery attribute selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465157/case-insensitive-jquery-attribute-selector)

Comment: What is the html for this doing? you'd want to change the data attribute  to something like  [data-destination*='/"+input+"/gi'] I think.

Comment: Beyond the answers marked as duplicated, can you change how the html is generated?  ie when you generate `<div data-destination=...` *make it lowercase at the point it is generated*.  Then you only need to convert the input to lower and compare.

Comment: @freedomn-m , thabk you for the idea, u saved my day

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
$(".filter").hide();
$("div[data-destination*='"+ input +"']").show();
```

with this:

```
$(".filter div[data-destination]").hide(); // You have to hide the elements (the divs you want to filter) not the container.
$(".filter div[data-destination]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("destination").toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}.show();
```

Comment: It didn't work , about '.filter' , it's the class of the full list, i hide it to show only the search result