# Jquery attribute - How to make the verification not case sensitive?

Tags: jquery, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS selector case insensitive for attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671238/css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes)

The here below code checks if an attribute of a given class, starts with the value that the user has entered in a given input

```
var inputVariable = $('#myInput').val();

$('.class[attribute ^= '+inputValue+']')......
```

My problem is that the attribute "verification' is case sensitive. I am looking for a solution to make it not case sensitive. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Comment: Ok Manse, I'll need time to test this out. Looks chinese to me for the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RegExp to compare the value of the attribute. See code: http://jsfiddle.net/djBsy/2/

Comment: Hello there. Your example is very interesting. I learned things. Nevertheless it is not working. if you type for instance selectorCaseInsensitive('.myClass', 'id', 'hsduqshudihqduisu'); the result is the same....

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The if condition was incorrect. I updated it and it works now :)

Comment: Your example made me understand how all this works (regexp...). So by adapting your example by modifiying it a bit I manage to get what I wanted. So thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var re = new RegExp("^"+inputValue, "i");
    $('.class').filter(function() {
        return (re).test( $(this).attr('attribute'));
    });
```

Comment: and what if the class on the DOM element is in all uppercase ! I think your miss reading the question

Comment: Hello DotMat. Thanks for helping out. The problem with your solution is that it only works in one direction. The thing is, the user can either enter a string that starts with an uppercase or lowercase in the input. So I need something working in the two directions... But anyway thanks for sharing this toLowerCase thing. I did not knew it.

Comment: Making the value lower case doesn't prevent the selector from being case sensitive... If the value of the attribute is "teSt" and the value of `inputValue` is "Test", the value of `inputValue.toLowerCase()` will be "test" and they still won't match.

Comment: Hello Anthony. Correct. Do you know a way to work around this?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I've just completed my answer.

Comment: @DotMat **read the question again** .... what if the class on the DOM element is "SOMEthing" .... what the OP needs is the search to be case-insensitive not convert everything to lowercase before searching