# HTML input search doesn't find uppercase vise versa

Tags: jquery, html, input, uppercase, lowercase

This code doesn't find `UPPERCASE` if searched for with lowercase `uppercase` vise versa same for `lowercase`, if searched for `LOWERCASE`.
I was thinking of making the input and data-label to lowercase with jquery before searching, but how?

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/jdmTZ/)

Can someone help, thanks

Comment: just make a comparison using `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`....pretty straight forward

Comment: I am no jquery Guru ...  Could you modify the jsfiddle code so it works? Thanks

Comment: You can find solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671238/css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/jdmTZ/5/

Remove the data attribute and add it in code:

```
            $('.filter li').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('data-label', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
            });
```

Then search by lowercased input

```
                var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace line 14 by this:

```
var matched = $("ul li").filter(function() { return $(this).data('label').toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0; });
```

And change the `show()`/`hide()` logic:

```
$('ul li').hide();
matched.show();
matched = matched.length;
```

[Complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bV2jd/)

This also eliminates the problem of someone entering `]` or some other special character - that would break the CSS rule in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toLowerCase()` and `$.each` [Updated js fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/jdmTZ/3/)