# Jquery case insensitive select

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know this is possible with the :contains selector IE:

[How do I make jQuery Contains case insensitive, including jQuery 1.8+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8)

But is this possible using similar logic:

```
 <input type="text" name="SomeThing-Really-Complex-and-Annoying" />
```

Can I select that element by it's name on a case insensitive level EG. This would work:

```
$('input[name="something-really-complex-and-annoying"]').addClass('yay');
```

if you see what I mean?

Comment: [css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5671252/1696560)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(':input[name]').filter(function() {
   return this.name.toLowerCase() == 'something-really.etc';
 });
```

Comment: `this.name` or `$(this).attr('name')` ;)

Comment: `:input` selector will select `all input, textarea, select and button elements.`.

Comment: Fantastic. Just the job. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: thanks @A.Wolff was not aware.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('input[type="text"][name]').filter(function() {
   return this.name.toLowerCase() == 'something-really-complex-and-annoying';
}).addClass("yay");
```

Comment: No @A.Wolff, when I was typing, JF's answer came

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't sure whose answer to accept, so just went for the first one.

Comment: @user1001421 its okay but remember that that answer will get all `select, all input, textarea, select and button elements.` which will be slower. My answer will be fast than the one you have accepted. Just saying

Comment: Good point. I kind of tweaked the answer anyhow to narrow down the selections. I just needed to be steered onto the right path :) Thanks mate.

Comment: You're always welcome