# What does "i" mean in a CSS attribute selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have found the following CSS selector in the Google Chrome user agent stylesheet:

```
[type="checkbox" i]
```

What does the `i` mean?

[image]

Comment: OP, is your document XHTML ?

Comment: This looks more like Chrome's user agent stylesheet and not a Zurb-specific issue.

Comment: I remember seeing this somewhere. Something's telling me it's to do with caps?

Comment: @dystroy: See my answer to [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050139/input-selector-mystery-i-inputtype-search-i-in-chrome) - whether the markup is HTML or XHTML actually makes no difference, both of them are case-sensitive with attributes. I'm kinda bummed that I never saw this question because of the downvotes, considering I'm probably in the best position to answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: Selectors level 4 is part of CSS3 - it is just the next level of a module that started out at level 3. "CSS4" is a misnomer.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the input, I've been going back and forth about this issue since I read that CSS4 is not an official name. While it may be a misnomer, it seems to be a popular one. I was considering bringing this up on meta. Any thoughts or should I revert the edit and let the tag die?

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: I would love to see it brought up on meta. In particular I'd like to know how we can handle the use of the [css4] tag - the most drastic measure I could take is make it a synonym of [css3], and that would actually be the right thing to do.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: Would you be cool with merging my answer into this question so both of our answers are located in one place?

Comment: @BoltClock Fine by me! It would be more-helpful for other users if it were all in one place. BTW, I'll have the meta question up soon!

Comment: @BoltClock [Meta Question is up!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/css4-tag-misnomer-or-useful) BTW, when you ask about merging your answer with this question, did you mean edit the question/answer here to add the information, or were you referring to a magic move-an-answer-to-another-question button?

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: Not moving individual answers, but combining two entire questions. It's a mod-only function.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I don't think it's a popular one in the use of *tags*, as you can see that this is the only question on the site with a [tag:css4] tag.

Comment: @TylerH We have [a discussion on Meta on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/css4-tag-misnomer-or-useful). Feel free to add to the discussion there.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is for case-insensitive attribute matching. [This is a new feature in CSS Selectors Level 4.](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case)

Presently it is available in Chrome 49+, Firefox 47+, Safari 9+, and Opera 37+*. Prior to this it was only available in the Chrome user-agent styles starting around Chrome 39, but could be enabled for web content by setting the experimental features flag.

* Earlier versions of Opera may also support it.

## Working Example / Browser Test:

```css
[data-test] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 4px;
}

[data-test="A"] {
    background: red;
}

[data-test="a" i] {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
Green if supported, red if not:

<div data-test="A"></div>
```

The above square will be green if the browser supports this feature, red if it does not.

Comment: Thanks for teaching! Enjoy your new hat. Does this sort of thing work in selector libraries? What sort of browser support does it have?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It looks like it's only available in Chrome user-agent styles (not a website's CSS, at least not yet). I could not find any official compatibility documentation.

Comment: (Reposting my earlier comment now that the questions are merged.) It's not entirely surprising that brand new, experimental standards such as this are poorly documented. That said, my answer contains some more information on this, namely how it works, why it is used, and how it is implemented in Chrome (as given by the question).

Comment: Chrome will add support for this in version 49.0 (currently in Beta), Firefox in version 47.0 (scheduled to be released in June 2016). Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Green if supported, red if not, none if your browser is bad and doesn't understand custom attribute CSS selectors.

Comment: @LWChris: I'm not sure any such browser actually exists. IE6 doesn't understand attribute selectors at all, and IE7 supports them even with custom data attributes.

Answer (score 36):

That is the case-insensitive flag for attribute selectors, introduced in [Selectors 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#attribute-case). Apparently they snuck an implementation of this feature into Chrome as early as August 2014.

In a nutshell: this flag tells the browser to match the respective values for the `type` attribute case-insensitively. The default selector matching behavior for attribute values in HTML is [case-sensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#case-sensitivity), which is often undesirable because many attributes are defined to have case-insensitive values, and you want to make sure your selector picks up all the right elements regardless of case. `type` is one example of such an attribute, because [it is an enumerated attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type), and [enumerated attributes are said to have case-insensitive values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attribute).

Here are the relevant commits:

- [179370](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=179370&view=revision) — implementation
- [179401](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=179401&view=revision) — changes to UA stylesheets as shown in the screenshot in the question

Note that it's currently hidden within the "Enable experimental Web Platform features" flag, which you can access at chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features. This might explain why the feature went largely unnoticed — features hidden behind that flag can only be used internally and not in public-facing code (such as author stylesheets) unless it is enabled, because they are experimental and therefore not ready for production use.

Here's a test case that you can use — compare the results when the flag is enabled and disabled:

```css
span[data-foo="bar"] {
    color: red;
}

span[data-foo="bar" i] {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<span data-foo="bar">If all of this text is green,</span>
<span data-foo="Bar">your browser supports case-insensitive attribute selectors.</span>
```

Note that I use a custom data attribute instead of `type` to show that it can be used with just about any attribute.

I am not aware of any other implementations as of this writing, but hopefully other browsers will catch up soon. This is a relatively simple but extremely useful addition to the standard and I look forward to being able to use it in future.

Comment: I'm having "that afternoon" fatigue... After reading the W3 spec im still not understanding completely, what would be a practical real life usage in css for this ?

Comment: @Matt: Attribute selector matching is case-sensitive as [stated in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#case-sensitivity), which in many cases is undesirable because HTML5 allows case-insensitive values for certain attributes. You can use this flag to ensure you pick up the right elements regardless of case. For example in the screenshot you can see that it looks for `input[type="search" i]`, which will match elements like `<input type="SEARCH">`.

Comment: I can confirm it working with Chromium Version 43.0.2357.130 and “Enable experimental Web Platform features” enabled.