# input selector mystery i input[type="search" i] in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I noticed this when i was inspecting the search `input` on the [**Zurb Foundation**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html#built-in-components) framework this afternoon. I've tweeted, and done an extensive search on Google but without any leads.

What exactly is the `i` for in `input[type="search" i]` ?

[image: Chrome User Agent Stylesheet]