# What does "i" mean in CSS attribute selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Recently I saw some CSS selectors in browsers default styles:

```
input[type="hidden" i] {
    display: none
}
```

What does "i" mean.

Source: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css at line 412

Comment: I hope it's just a coincidence that this is **almost word-for-word** a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector

Comment: am pretty sure that you got this question while writing yours as related ... but no one pay attention to them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

> Adding an i (or I) before the closing bracket causes the value to be compared case-insensitively (for characters within the ASCII range).

So this selector will match `type="hidden"`, `type="HIDDEN"`, etc.