# What is the purpose of 'i' in this css rule : input[type="color" i]?

Tags: css, google-chrome

What does the "i" stand for in this css rule defined by the user-agent default stylesheet (chromium 81)?

```
input[type="color" i] { /* user agent stylesheet */
    ...
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

And can I define my own rule to unset the padding?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "i" mean in a CSS attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector)

Comment: Yes it does. I did know about the others operators but not about the long awaited case insensitivity. It will make my like easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See an answer in [What does "i" mean in a CSS attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector).

For unset the padding, you can create your own `input[type="color"]`. If the order is not okay, add `!important` after padding (eg. `padding: 1px 2px !important;`).

Comment: Some friendly advice, since you're new here: Instead of linking or quoting a duplicate answer, just flag it. It helps our system to stay clean. Flags on Stack Overflow are not meant to punish people, they are educational and will not subtract reputation from them (except spam flags or abusive flags). If you still wanna answer to gain some reputation, do it, but keep in mind: Authors will probably delete their answer with many down votes to get their reputation back and that will also apply to you too, but negatively.