# Case insensitive attribute flag in conjunction with :visible selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

This works

```
$('input[name=email i]')
```

And this works

```
$('input[name=email]:visible')
```

But this doesn't work (unrecognized expression)

```
$('input[name=email i]:visible')
```

Why?

Comment: Post an HTML example that you're using this against please

Comment: The HTML doesn't matter since it throws an exception `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=email i]:visible`

Comment: Seriously, we harp so much on making reproducible examples as minimal as humanly possible... yet we keep asking people to pad out their questions with unnecessary HTML, for what exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because jQuery switches selector engines depending on the selector it's given. By default, when given a valid CSS selector jQuery passes it to the browser's native selector engine via `document.querySelectorAll()` to match elements. This is to maximize performance.

On the other hand, when given a non-standard selector, jQuery uses its own Sizzle engine to match elements so that it can evaluate its own non-standard selectors. `:visible` is one such selector, therefore only Sizzle understands it and it is required for matching.

The `i` flag is [new to Selectors 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector/28050505#28050505), and is not implemented in Sizzle. The latest version of every modern browser [now supports this feature](https://caniuse.com/css-case-insensitive), so a selector like

```js
$('input[name=email i]')
```

will work in every modern browser due to the use of `document.querySelectorAll()`. However in older versions that don't support it, this will be treated as an invalid CSS selector and handled by Sizzle as a result. In those cases, this selector would not work at all.

Adding jQuery's own `:visible` to the selector forces jQuery to use Sizzle. But since Sizzle doesn't recognize the `i` flag, the selector expression is deemed unrecognized.

You can resolve this by separating the `:visible` from the rest of your selector so that the browser can handle the `i` flag and Sizzle can handle `:visible`. You can do this using `.filter()`:

```js
$('input[name=email i]').filter(':visible')
```