# JQuery how to .find() case insensitive?

Tags: jquery

```
<Manufacturers>
  <Manufacturer name="abc">
    <flags=""/>
  </Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcd">
    <flags=""/>
  </Manufacturer>
  <Manufacturer name="abcde">
    <flags=""/>
  </Manufacturer>
<Manufacturers>
```

I want to print out the names of just the manufacturers which contain the string 'bc' in the name

This is my attempt so far

```
      $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $(this);
        html = "";
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "./Sources.xml",
                datatype: "xml",
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(xml.toLowerCase()) {
                    console.log('AJAX Request is succeded.');

                    $(xml).find('Manufacturer[name*="' + $(data.input).val() + '"]').each(function(){
                        console.log($(this).attr('name'));
                    });
                    $ul.html(html);
                    $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                    $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
                }
            });

    });
```

The problem is that .find() is case sensitive. How can I do the same but case insensitive

Comment: You have to use a "filter" function as in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671238/css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes

Comment: I did stumble across that function but I can't figure out how to implement it for my code example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than building your check into your find, you should match off of "Manufacturer", and then search by the name of the manufacturer and the query both cast to lower case within the function

```
$(xml).find("Manufacturer").each(function(i){
  console.log($(this)[0].attributes.name.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
})
```

Comment: It won't get past the .find() as that is the case sensitive issue i'm having

Comment: And what is $(xml) returning in this case?

Comment: Updated my answer.  I was using a fake xml return, so it may not work exactly right, but that's the gist.

Comment: Getting there, but it only works of the they are exact matches. I need it work if the "Manufacturer" contains the query

Comment: Updated my answer, go ahead and try that out.  It's checking to see if the query is a substring within the manufacturer name.  So "toy" would find true on "Toyota".  `"Toyota".toLowerCase().indexOf("toY".toLowerCase()) >= 0` returns `true`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var xml = '<Manufacturers><Manufacturer name="abc"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcd"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcde"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturers>';

// we create a jQuery objecct from the xml string (above),
// find all the Manufacturer elements,
// filter those elements using the filter() method:
var bcInName = $(xml).find('Manufacturer').filter(function() {
  // keeping only those elements in which the lower-cased 'name'
  // attribute contains the string 'bc':
  return this.attributes["name"].value.toLowerCase().indexOf('bc') > -1;
// using map() to create a map:
}).map(function() {
  // consisting of the value of the name attribute from the
  // elements that we kept in the collection:
  return this.attributes["name"].value;
// using get() to convert the map to an array:
}).get();

// using this to write a log in the 'result' pane of
// of the snippet:
snippet.log(bcInName);

// logging to the console:
console.log(bcInName);
```

```js
var xml = '<Manufacturers><Manufacturer name="abc"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcd"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcde"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturers>';



var bcInName = $(xml).find('Manufacturer').filter(function() {
  return this.attributes["name"].value.toLowerCase().indexOf('bc') > -1;
}).map(function() {
  return this.attributes["name"].value;
}).get();

snippet.log(bcInName);
console.log(bcInName);
```

```css
p::before {
  content: 'Names found: ';
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2o9zn3mg/1/), for experimentation.

Incidentally, it's worth noting that, in the Selectors Level 4 Module of CSS, case-insensitive attribute-selectors will – unless the selector is removed from the module at a future point – be allowed via the following notation:

```
[frame=hsides i] {
    border-style: solid none;
}
```

Note the space between the `hsides` and the `i` identifier, which will:

> …style the [element with the] frame attribute when it has a value of hsides, whether that value is represented as `hsides`, `HSIDES`, `hSides`, etc. even in an XML environment where attribute values are case-sensitive.

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Attribute-selectors, case-insensitivity](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#attribute-case).
- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this jQuery issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1991), the `children()` function is case sensitive, so you could use it instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ucx4j0yy/)):

```
var xml = '<Manufacturers><Manufacturer name="abc"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcd"><flags=""/></Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcde"><flags=""/></Manufacturer></Manufacturers>',
  $results = $( xml ).children( 'Manufacturer[name*="' + $(data.input).val() + '"]' );

$( "#result" ).append( '# results = ' + $results.length );
```

Comment: I think the "case insensitivity" only deals with xml object name and not attributes...