# change first attribute only while there are 2 having the same name in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have searched everywhere I couldn't find an answer to this

```
thisObj.$playpauseButton.find('svg').attr('viewBox',newSvgData[0]);

<svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="-40 -130 500 600" viewbox="-28 -140 500 600">
```

The code here only changes the last viewbox attribute not both of them,
How can I select both or select the first one only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also jQuery [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Now, your script should look like this

```
$('.able-button-handler-play').find('svg').eq(0).setAttribute('viewBox','-28 -140 500 600');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to use setAttribute() as it's case sensitive.

[As in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042694/jquery-attr-seems-to-be-case-sensitive)

```
$('.able-button-handler-play').find('svg')[0].setAttribute('viewBox','-28 -140 500 600');
```