# Can't use custom selector as a selector in the ON event

Tags: jquery

```
    $.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
       if (! obj.href.match (new RegExp ("^http"))) {
      return (false);
}

return (true);
}
```

I have a custom jquery selector above. It checks for an external link. I call it using:

```
 $('a:external')
              .on ('click', function (e) {
        do_stuff ();
    });
```

Above works great. But below does not. Basically I need to do the below because I load in some content via ajax and I need to check for external links still. I figured the below would work but no luck. If I were to remove the :external from below it works on all links as expected. But adding the selector of :external doesn't produce an event when I click on the link. Any ideas?

```
$('body')
          .on ('click', 'a:external', function (e) {
        do_stuff ();
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.8 or higher? If that's the case, can you reproduce the problem if you create your custom selector through `$.expr.createPseudo()`, as detailed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12099447/464709)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Yes. Same problem.

Comment: Can you not have a custom selector when you have a delegated event?