# Non-case-sensitive comparison of text input value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, selector

I have looked through the answers relating to writing custom selectors in JQuery (such as this one: [Writing jQuery selector case-insensitive version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967869/writing-jquery-selector-case-insensitive-version)) but am still unclear on if a custom selector is the best approach to my problem.

I want to take input from a text box and compare it to a list of known terms. I want the comparison to be case insensitive. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 $('#query').change(function() {   
    if ($("#query").val() == "kittens") {
       $('#change').text("kittens")
    }
    else if ($("#query").val() == "puppies") {
       $('#change').text("puppies")
    }
    else {
       $('#change').text("neither kittens nor puppies")
    }
 });
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcbMQ/

I want "kittens" and "Kittens" and "KITTENS" to all match the kitten condition. I am not clear that a custom selector is the best way to do this, or if I can use .is() or similar. If a custom selector is the best way to do it, how/where do I integrate that into my code?

UPDATE:

Here is a JSFiddle with the working code, thanks to dystroy:
http://jsfiddle.net/XcbMQ/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
if ($("#query").val().toLowerCase() == "kittens") {
```

Comment: or `toUpperCase()` as mentioned by @David Hedlund

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration of where to add the .toLowerCase() to my code, made it very simple to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that uses `switch` instead of multiple if statements.  Does the same job but is a bit tidier...

```
$('#change').text("nothing entered yet")

$('#query').change(function() {   
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    switch (text) {
        case "kittens":
            $('#change').text("kittens");
            break;
        case "puppies":
            $('#change').text("puppies");
            break;
        default:
            $('#change').text("neither kittens nor puppies");    
            break;
    }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/XcbMQ/3/