# Making jQuery completely case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, case-sensitive

I'm using jQuery for automated testing. The HTML for different parts of the application looks very much alike, but sometimes capitalization of class names, ids, and styles is different.

For instance, the class for result tables is sometines 'Grid', sometimes 'grid'.

So I need to use different jQuery expressions in the test code (in Java):

```
public String getResultCell(int row, int colum) throws Exception {
  return _browser.evaluateJavaScript("$('table.Grid').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(" + row + ").find('td').eq(" + colum + ").text()").trim();
}
```

And sometimes

```
// FIXME: fix case sensitivity
public String getResultCell(int row, int colum) throws Exception {
  return _browser.evaluateJavaScript("$('table.grid').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(" + row + ").find('td').eq(" + colum + ").text()").trim();
}
```

Is there a way to make jQuery case-insensitive altogether?

Comment: How about actually fixing the problem? If those class names are supposed to mean the same, make them the same.

Comment: Agreed with Cerbrus, give both classes the same name. `class="grid"` in your HTML everywhere instead of both "Grid" and "grid".

Comment: I'm only writing the tests, not the application. I can probably get those class names fixed. At the same time, I want to write stable test code that doesn't depend on capitalization.

Comment: Consistency isn't a test criteria? You seem to be working around a bug in the system to write tests that work.

Comment: I agree that it's a bug in the system that must be fixed. But I would consider it an improvement if the tests were case-insensitive, not a work around.

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967869/writing-jquery-selector-case-insensitive-version

Comment: Thanks, Cerbrus. It seems quite messy. It's probably better to clean up the HTML first.

Answer (score 1):

This jquery code should find table by class name and not depend on case

```
var classname = 'grid';
$('table').filter(function(){
   return (" "+$(this).get(0).className.toLowerCase()+" ".indexOf(' '+classname.toLowerCase()+' ')!=-1);
});
```

You may wrap this as a jquery method:

```
$.fn.filterByClass = function (classname) {
    return $(this).filter(function(){
       return (" "+$(this).get(0).className.toLowerCase()+" ".indexOf(' '+classname.toLowerCase()+' ')!=-1);
    });
};
```

and then use this like this: `$('table').filterByClass('grid')`

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nu32e/)

Comment: Thanks for the code to handle class selectors. But I hoped there was a more generic solution that applies to all selectors.