# Match a string in jQuery regardless of upper/lower case

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to match words on the page by using :contains, If i'm searching for the word "string" I want to be able to match "STRING","sTRiNg" etc. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an answer here:
[Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)