# Jquery read more link to add class

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible for Jquery to add a class to a link that says read more automatically?

I want to use this within a CMS and for it to automatically turn any read more link into a button by adding a class.

Comment: Yahh, its Possible. But please share some code which you want to change.

Comment: ??  what do you mean by "read more"  ??

Comment: @Thariama: think Wordpress, where clicking 'Read more >>' type link shows the rest of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep:

```
$('a:contains("read more")').addClass('newlyAddedClass');
```

This will add the class 'newlyAddedClass' to every element that contains the string 'read more', it is case-sensitive, and relies on the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector.

Comment: I tried the class above, but for some reason doesn't seem to apply. An example link would be `code`<a href="http://localhost:8888/creativejunction/about-us/sounding-boards"> Read More &raquo; </a>`code`

Comment: @Matt: did you notice the part where I said '[it's] case-sensitive'? If it still doesn't work, put together a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo of what you're working with and I'll take a look.

Comment: It works! It is case-sensitive. Look at this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dDbEu/1/.

Comment: @Matt: glad to have been of help =)

Comment: I have just been testing this in IE6 and IE7 on browserlab and the class doesn't seem to be added. I have read that this might be due to slower timing, but tried delaying and still not showing. Is there any problems with the JQuery add class in IE?

Comment: @Matt: off-hand, I don't know (I'm a hobbyist, and run Linux, so...). However: are you using a doctype, because IE 7 should certainly be able to handle the (minimal) requirements of this jQuery.

Comment: Looking into this in more detail, and testing in IE 6 and 7, errors on the page were causing this not to load correctly. weirdly only showing in IE6/7. Thank you again for your help, and patience! Regards

Answer (score 0):

try some class or id

**..a href="---" class="myreadmore" id="myreadmore">read more  ../a>**

```
            with class

            $('.myreadmore').addClass("myclass");   

            with id

            $('#myreadmore').addClass("myclass");
```

or use

```
contains("Read More &raquo;")
```

check previous anwere

refer http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
for contains selector

Answer (score 0):

The following code will add a case insensitive `Contains` (Note the uppercase C) selector to jQuery

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
  return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase())>=0;
};
```

You can then use a slightly modified version of David Thomas' code:

```
$('a:Contains("read more")').addClass('newlyAddedClass');
```

Which will case insensitively match everything with "read more" (So also "Read More", "rEAd More" etc.)

*Found the selector in the following question: [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)*