# Hide Links not containing my Keyword (Case Sensitive)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this shopping cart script that sends Links to my own website. Meaning I have no control over the HTML.

The links look like this:

```
<a href="something.com">Yamaha 800cc motorbike</a>
<a href="something.com">800cc Kawasaki</a>
<a href="something.com">Motorbike 1000cc Honda</a>
```

And there are variations in which the anchor text Casing is different as well.

ie:

```
<a href="something.com">YAMAHA 800cc motorbike</a>
<a href="something.com">yamaha 1000cc motorbike</a>
```

My Goal:

**HIDE all Links that Do Not have Yamaha, yamaha or YAMAHA in the anchor text.**
(all text casings)

To end up with Yamaha motorbikes only.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks and best regards,

Chakhun

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector

Answer (score 3):

Could look like:

```
$('a').each(function(_, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    if( !/yamaha/i.test( $elem.text() ) )
        $elem.hide();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/r4Yeh/2

Comment: Thanks jAndy
I don't see the all lower case link "yamaha 1000cc motorbike"
The other ones seem to be working :-)

Comment: @Chakhun: indeed my bad. Fixed that now. You should go with Alex' suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').filter(function() {
   return ! $(this).text().match(/Yamaha/i);  
}).hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tHVgt/).

Comment: This one seems to do the trick :-)

Thanks Alex, much appreciate your help

Comment: @Chakhun Feel free to give me the big green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of  [:contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
<script>
$("a:contains('YAMAHA')").css("display", "inline");
    </script>
```

for more details about this : [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

Comment: `:contains()` is case sensitive.

Comment: I need to make the links NOT containing Yamaha invisible.
Links NOT containing YAMAHA or yamaha should disappear as well

Comment: @Chakhun - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector answer of your question

Comment: I don't think `visible` is a valid value of the `display` property.