# Is there a way to link to a specific paragraph on a page without anchors?

Tags: html, hyperlink, focus, anchor

I'm trying to write a post with form fill tutorial. There are a lot of sources, but source pages doesn't provide anchors on pages.

---

So my question is , how to make links to concrete paragraphs of text on html pages?

Is it possible at all?

Are there any JavaScript tricks in the url to achieve that?

---

**edit**:

I need to make link to particular paragraph on external source. For example to paragraph beginning with words "The Navy traces its origins to the" on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Navy) Wikipedia's page

Comment: Do you mean, link to a particular place on the page *without* the use of [anchors](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm)?

Comment: If you're open to using jQuery, then this post might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: @nashyura not even close. I need to make external link to source, it means on particular paragraph on external html page

Comment: You could probably use JavaScript to scroll to that part of the page, but this would be very fragile, because it would break if the sentence was reworded.

Comment: @ThatMatthew tell me how, cause my sources are official and probably not going to be changed

Comment: This looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795299/javascript-find-text-on-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only link to named anchors or elements with ids. If the target page has neither you are out of luck.

Comment: thanks. but is that all? I know, that I can enumerate paragraphs on page. Is there a way to focus on particular paragraph using url?

Comment: If you want to do it using purely the URL only, there's nothing you can do. If you embed the page in an iframe you have a bit more control.

Comment: maybe interesting. could you provide an example?

Answer (score 8):

As of 2020, there is a draft by WICG for **[Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/#indicating-the-text-match)**, and now you can link to text on a page as if you were searching for it by adding the following to the hash

`#:~:text=<Text To Link to>`

Working example on `Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138`:

[Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12061174/614277#:~:text=Click%20on%20this%20link) Should reload the page and highlight the link's text

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed, that you want this on external source.
If there are ids, you can use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/LCgge/

Comment: Sorry, but there are even no id on paragraphs (((