# Find text on page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, search, escaping

There have been questions about this in the past (not very recent from what I can tell.) It's clear that $(:contains()) can work, however my text has protected characters. I know I can escape this with regex, but I'd like to avoid the extra cost if possible. So, I'm wondering if there is a standard solution to this problem, perhaps a function I can call? Or even, is it possible to call jQuery's `contains` without having to pass it through a string selector?

In my case I only need the first result, if theres any algorithms that consider that, and I also need to be able to manipulate the containing element or at least replace the relevant text.

Comment: What are "protected characters"?

Comment: Well, () for example through errors with :contains, I'm sure there are plenty of others

Comment: Can you include example of `html`  and description of expected result at Question?

Comment: I think you might find answer to your question by going [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795299/javascript-find-text-on-page)

Comment: I think each of these answers has their own (avoidable) problems @SulavDepp but thanks