# Jquery search multidimensional ul list

Tags: jquery

I have next HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="search" name="searchword" value="" />
<ul id="search_list">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third
        <ul>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>bbbb
                <ul>
                    <li>111111</li>
                    <li>22222</li>
                    <li>3333</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>cccc</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to search this list via input.
I type text into input and `<li>` and `<ul>`'s which are not search result must hide.

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you tried to write the code to do this? What is an example search input?

Comment: let suppose that I type into input "11".
I that case <li>first</li> and <li>second</li> should hide because they are not search result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use keyup, blur or change depending when you want the search and filter to take place.

```
$('#search').change(function() {
   var searchTerms = $(this).val();

   $('li').each(function() {
      var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 || $(this).is(':contains(' + searchTerms  + ')');

      $(this).toggle(hasMatch);
   });
});
```

EDIT: Made the solution slightly more verbose so it can be read easier.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cg7SM/).

Comment: Excellent, would never say it's that simple.

Thank you very much.

Comment: +1: I suggest adding a fallback for nothing in the search box, e.g. `if(searchTerms.length==0){ $('li').show(); return; }`

Comment: Good idea, since I'm pretty sure having nothing in the search box will fail it.

Comment: @Wizard4U after var searchTerms ... or insert it at the hasMatch as I did (see updated solution).  Performance is negligible in this case.  If it did matter then I recommend not even using .show()/.hide() but that's another discussion all together.

Comment: Can I search not depending on CAPS LOCK ?

Comment: Yes but it requires a small change - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector

Comment: Yes, I have founded that but I do not know how to use.
A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Solved. Thank you. This is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector/4936066#4936066