# Click a Link Using jQuery based on the Text Inside the Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about clicking a link using jQuery, with the text inside the link.

I.E.:

```
<a href="/node/1744650/nodequeue">Nodequeue</a>
```

I want to click this link based entirely on the fact that Nodequeue is inside the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a:contains("Nodequeue")').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `contains:` selector:

```
$('a:contains("Nodequeue")').click();
```

For more information about the selector, have a look at the documentation for it [here](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Please note that it is case-sensitive, if you are looking for case insensitive search, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector).

Comment: I tried that, and it kept giving me an error message. One of my other questions touches on this error message, I will post it here later (I am at work currently and do not have the ability to generate the debug code atm)