# jQuery usage of contains and toLowerCase()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to compare a string given in an input to a div's content using jQuery `contain`.

Problem is, I want to be able to check if the string is contained regardless of upper/lower case.

This is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawDimensions('dContent');
    $('#dSuggest').keyup(function() {
        var dInput = this.value;
        $(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

So if one of the .dDimension divs contains 'Date' and a user presses the 'd' key, I want to show that item.

is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`.filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var dInput = this.value.toLowerCase();

$(".dDimension").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(dInput) > -1;
}).css("display","block");
```

Comment: can I use the ``not`` function to check the opposite?

Comment: Sure. Or you change `> -1` to `=== -1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own selector by extending jQuery. Try this

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
  {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
    .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});
```

Useage `$(".dDimension:containsi('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this example](http://shareourideas.com/2011/03/28/jquery-contains-with-case-insensitive/), he extend the jQuery selectors with a case-insensitive contains selector that he calls containsi, like this:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
   'containsi': function (elem, i, match, array) {
       return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || '').toLowerCase()) >= 0;
   }
});
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same what [ShankarSangoli posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8795791/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, that seems to be the exact same thing. Without the ref to the original author though :)

Answer (score 0):

The last comments in [the jQuery documentation for contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) provides an 'icontains' implementation that may suit you.

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(meta[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};

// Example usage.
$("div:icontains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```