# Using .val() and toLowercase together causes a cannot read property error

Tags: jquery

I am storing form field values as variables. When I look in the console, `toLowerCase()` is not recognized.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$("#Regbutton").click(function() {
var email = $('#email').val().toLowerCase();
alert(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="Regbutton"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?  Your snippet works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795752/jquery-usage-of-contains-and-tolowercase

Comment: @Jules can't see where this question is trying to filter elements based on content

Comment: OK so those were some pretty bad typos apologies @freedomn-m

It may just be that CodePen doesn't like it for whatever reason..

I am using 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Also works ok in jsfiddle with jquery 3.1.1: https://jsfiddle.net/8xjt4bvy/.   Have a look at [mcve] and see if you can create a snippet/fiddle that reproduces the error.